# ABP tenant creation is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, sqlclient

I am evaluating ABP 3.9 currently and tenant creation is not working.

It's failing while executing this code:

```
CheckErrors(await _roleManager.CreateStaticRoles(tenant.Id));
```

This is the exception that I am getting:

```
Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
```

The same Entity Framework connection works with other `ApplicationService` classes that I have added. Don't know why only for tenant creation this fails. I am extending the sample template, which is available freely on ASP.NET Boilerplate site.

Thanks a lot for the help.
Regards,
Zainu

Comment: You passed a malformed connection string for the new tenant.

Comment: Thanks.Tweaking the code to accept default connection string helped.

Comment: Would you like to post a complete answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize till the code was deployed in Azure that it would end up with exception "System.ApplicationException: Could not find content root folder".

Lucky for me that there was a discussion on the same here https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-templates/issues/43 and the fix was the same

var startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var configuration = AppConfigurations.Get(startupPath); 
tenant.ConnectionString = SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(configuration.GetConnectionString(OneCloudConsts.ConnectionStringName));

Answer (score 0):

In TenantAppService class under Create method commented out the code which created encrypted connection string from input DTO. Added a way to read connection string from configuration and this worked in my case since I have a single database for all tenants.This database would be very small and it would store only metadata about Tenants while majority of Application data would be in Azure storage.

```
    public override async Task<TenantDto> Create(CreateTenantDto input)
    {
        CheckCreatePermission();

        // Create tenant
        var tenant = ObjectMapper.Map<Tenant>(input);
        //this code is commented since we have single database for all tenants
        //tenant.ConnectionString = input.ConnectionString.IsNullOrEmpty()
        //    ? null
        //    : SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(input.ConnectionString);

        //This would read connection string from configuration and pass it to 
       //connectionstring property of AbpTenant
        var configuration = 
       AppConfigurations.Get(WebContentDirectoryFinder.CalculateContentRootFolder());
        tenant.ConnectionString = SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(configuration.GetConnectionString(OneCloudConsts.ConnectionStringName));
```